# Select query is throwing error using where clause in node js and express API

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, angular6

my below code is showing error while select query is using with where clause 
please reply me soon anybody

```
exports.findById = (req, res) => {  
const id = req.params.id;
con.query('SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = ?', id,(err, result)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    res.json(result.id);
})
```

};

Thanks

Comment: Why id = ? ......

Answer (score 0):

A `con.query` method expects a valid SQL syntax, in your case, it would look something like this `SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = 1`

And since you are trying to `prepare` a SQL query, the `con.fomrat` method is the one you are looking for.

So the end result should look something like the following

```js
exports.findById = (req, res) => {  
const id = req.params.id;
con.query(
  con.format(
    'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = ?',
    [
      id,
    ]
  ),
  (err, result) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.json(result.id)
  }
);
```